# I can't remember the word to describe sleazy politicians who just make fake promises?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word i think start from D but i could be wrong. Its is used to describe politician who duped people by making tall promises but don't do anything. 
Please Help

Comment: The word is just *politicians*!

Comment: Theresa May in the UK made much of her concern for the *Just-About-Managing (JAM)* "squeezed middle" class. Much derided by those who associate the term with being offered [***Jam tomorrow, and jam yesterday - but never jam today***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam_tomorrow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the word you are remembering is *demagogue*. However, this one doesn't mean what you said. A demagogue is a politician that appeals to what people want, or think they want, as opposed to one that follows policies that are logical, or reasonable, even if unpopular.

Comment: This may be what OP *thinks* he wants, but I don't think there's any natural / inherent link between demagogic politicians (those who primarily appeal to the ***prejudices*** of the electorate, ***populists***), and politicians who ***fail to deliver*** whatever they promised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No one has claimed that there is.

Comment: That's true, and I do note that your answer specifically points out to OP that *this one doesn't mean what you said*. But to my mind, whereas that's a perfectly valid / relevant *comment*, it's not a valid "Answer" (even if OP *thinks* it is). It's perhaps ironic that your answer itself makes a distinction between what people *want*, and what they ***think** they want*. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Better to actually solve the OP's problem than to rant about baseless bullshit, or trying to build straw-men to have something to fight with.

Comment: There's supposed to be a guiding principle on all SO sites that when people ask questions, there should be at least the possibility of a single unambiguously correct answer. I'm not trying to pick a pointless argument with you. I simply thought I owed you an explanation as to why I downvoted your contribution here. But having reconsidered, I've decided to closevote the question itself - if it *does* actually get closed, *and* if I remember, I might come back and reverse my downvote on this answer, since my reason would no longer be particularly relevant.